# I have got extra 10 votes, but still unable to vote

Tags: bug, badges, votes

I have reached my daily vote limit:

> Daily vote limit reached; vote again in 15 hours.

Aftwer 2 hours, I earned **Vox Populi** badge:

> You've earned the "Vox Populi" badge (Use the maximum 40 votes in a day).

I am still unable to vote, even I should have now 10 votes left!

> Daily vote limit reached; vote again in 13 hours.

Is this a bug or something?

### Update:

After hours still getting the same thing:

> Daily vote limit reached; vote again in 3 hours.

Comment: I think sometimes it takes some time until the new quota gets updated?

Comment: That's a lot of voting! Thanks for doing your part. Perhaps at the end of the day you get given a new vote allocation which takes into account the new badge. I think a SO employee/developer might be needed to answer this